# C# Equivalent of Snoopy

Tags: c#, php, snoopy

[Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) is a PHP class that provides the functionality of a web-browser.  Is there anything that does the same in C#?  I'm having lots of trouble with handling cookies, etc.

Comment: Don't really understand what you want from us... Could you rewrite?

Comment: I'm not terribly sure what you're asking here but if you need to interface with some PHP code from C#, then Phalanger might be an option: http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=Phalanger

Comment: Please re-format as a proper question, and provide some more information both on Snoopy (as background), and on what you'd like to achieve in C#.

Comment: The post makes absolutely no sense...

Comment: @Oskar, SLaks & Johannes: He wants a similar library to Snoopy (which emulates web browsing in PHP) in C#, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Wow. I think he wants a C# version of snoopy. That's my best guess. Searching c# snoopy in google yields some funny results.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not quite what ш want. Now I try to login to forum vbulletin and similar others, but I can not. Using HttpWebRequest - difficult to work with Cookies. Maybe you tell my how do I log in the forum and other?

Answer (score 1):

What about Snoopy do you need? There is a [WebBrowser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) in C#

You don't specify what about cookies are giving you problems, so this is the best I can do for now for that part:

- http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+cookies
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+cookies

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing would be [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28VS.71%29.aspx) - you create one like this:

```
HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/");
//set request properties

//get response
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And you can then set headers, cookies etc. You could write your own wrapper class to give it an interface similar to Snoopy.